# Failed to Sync Repository

Tags: google-cloud-build

[image]
Sync Failed in Cloud source repository, Build trigger is not working when code is pushed.

Comment: I'm getting this as well. GCP or bitbucket might be having an issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue for it -https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146050155